# django.jQuery with django admin change_form.html

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to use the django's jQuery library as follows.  domain is a select field with id =id_domain on the form with form id = emailaccount_form. These ids are auto generated by django.

In the static file test.js code for jquery is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
    var form = $("emailaccount_form");
    var domain = $("id_domain");
    //number of domains include null as 1 value
    alert(domain.length);
    if ((!domain[0].value) && (domain.length > 1)){ 
        if (domain.length == 2){ 
        //select domain by default as it is the only available choice
        domain.selectedIndex = 1;
        alert('Domain ' + domain.value);
        }
    }
    });
})(django.jQuery);
</script>
```

On execution, I find that the domain.length value is 0, whereas there are actually 2 options in the select choices. Why? domain if displayed as alert(domain) displays object Object and not as object HTMLSelectElement.

Consider the 2nd case a javascript as below where I get the expected results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var domain = document.getElementById("{{ adminform.form.domain.auto_id }}");
   alert(domain);
   alert ("Number of domains: " + (domain.length-1));
   </script>
```

What is wrong with the django.jQuery. Can anyone guide? Also how do I get rid of the 1st blank value of the Select box as one of the options. I want to use django.jQuery only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply missing a hash mark? Remember jQuery needs one out front to select ID's, whereas JavaScript's native getElementById does not.

```
var form = $("#emailaccount_form");
var domain = $("#id_domain");
```

Comment: Lol - such a simple answer and yet correct (I think) :) Good catch

Comment: Thanx just my 2nd day at jQuery

Comment: also how to set the selectedIndex property in case there is only 1 choice in the select dropdown in jquery

Comment: I think you can use $('select').val('text value of dropdown here') ? but to be honest I haven't used that trick in some time.

Comment: I used $('#select')[0].selectedIndex = "some integer value"  it worked great. Thanx bahoo!